Calculating a definite improper integral
I want to calculate an integral of the form
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^p(1+x)^{-p-1}}{r+sx}dx$$
The answer can be found in terms of Gauss hypergeometric function. However, there this formula (equation 15.6.2_5) for ${}_2F_1$ in DLMF
$$\mathbf{F}\left(a,b;c;z\right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(b\right)\Gamma\left(c-b%
\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{b-1}\left(t+1\right)^{a-c}}{\left(t-zt+1%
\right)^{a}}\,\mathrm{d}t, \Re c>\Re b > 0, \vert\text{arg} \left(1-z\right)\vert<\pi$$
And there is this formula for ${}_2F_1$ in Wolfram function library
$$F\left(a,b;c;z\right)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma\left(b\right)\Gamma\left(c-b%
\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{-b+c-1}\left(t+1\right)^{a-c}}{\left(t-z+1%
\right)^{a}}\,\mathrm{d}t , \Re c>\Re b > 0, \vert\text{arg} \left(1-z\right)\vert<\pi$$
Now I am confused! Which one of these equations is correct?

Hint: How does the DLMF version transform under the $u$-substitution $u=1/t$?

Por que no los dos?

@Semiclassical Thank you! With $u = 1/t$ change of variable we get the integral $\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(b\right)\Gamma\left(c-b
\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{-b+c-1}\left(u+1\right)^{a-c}}{\left(u-z+1
\right)^{a}},\mathrm{d}u$ however, a $\Gamma(c)$ coefficient is still missing

See https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.1#E2. (The DLMF identity is for the bolded 2F1 definition, whereas the Wolfram version is for the un-bolded definition.)

@Semiclassical, thank you, it's perfect now, they are equivalent!
